# BUNDLE ./index.js error: index.js: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: react-native, macos, debugging, build, metro-bundler

I am not able to get rid of this error. I have installed react-native-community/cli so I am not sure why it showing that it is not there. I have tried everything on this link: facebook/react-native#34315
Please help me out.

Result of npx react-native-info:

System:
OS: macOS 13.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 83.02 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell:
version: 5.8.1
path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node:
version: 18.16.1
path: /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn:
version: 1.22.19
path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm:
version: 9.5.1
path: /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman:
version: 2023.07.10.00
path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods:
version: 1.12.1
path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms:

- DriverKit 22.4
- iOS 16.4
- macOS 13.3
- tvOS 16.4
- watchOS 9.4
  Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
  Xcode:
  version: 14.3.1/14E300c
  path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
  Java: Not Found
  Ruby:
  version: 2.6.10
  path: /usr/bin/ruby
  npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
  installed: 18.2.0
  wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
  installed: 0.72.3
  wanted: 0.72.3
  react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
  "react-native": Not Found
  Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
  iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false

Comment: Can you try to console.log('appName : ', appName) before the AppRegistry statement and see whether it is defined or undefined?

Comment: On the console, nothing showed up. Just the same error preventing me from running the app. The build is successful.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I was also stuck on this for hours. But then I found the solution in this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34315#issuecomment-1769250054). Basically:

- Install "metro": "^0.79.1"
- Install "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.0"
- Add this key to your package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
  "metro": "0.79.1"
}
```

Make sure that your package.json resembles [this](https://github.com/lovegaoshi/azusa-player-mobile/commit/84a779ff0158474951ab12a06c129a5b873763eb). Adding a resolutions key in package.json ensures that the specified version of Metro (0.79.1) is used in the project. This step overrides any other nested dependency versions of Metro.